# Angular entryComponents control from lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, dynamic, module, components, lazy-evaluation

I'm having two modules - one eagerly loaded which provides service and the component for modal displaying.

The other one - lazy laoded module.

My goal is to allow the lazy loaded module to call the following function:

```
this.modalService.open(UserAddFormComponent);
```

Which will appear in the for loop in the modal container component:

```
<cc-generic-modal *ngFor="let modal of modals"
                  [component]="modal.component">
</cc-generic-modal>
```

And the cc-generic-modal codes is very similar to angular's provided: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

The problem I'm facing is connected with the entryComponents. When I'm trying to call the modal I'm getting an error saying that I need to provide the entry component in the entryComponents list. But the list in lazy loaded component is not passed in the component that displays the cc-generic-modal.

If I were to add the UserAddFormComponent into the modal container component's entryComponenets list - the problem solves. But this solution does not fit me as the app will grow and this component can have over a hundred of entry componenets...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check how `ngComponentOutlet` uses module factory to get `entryComponents` from lazy loaded module https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_component_outlet.ts

Comment: If you want to work with a dynamic component it has to be added to the entry components. Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) to learn why